# How to load already instantiated JComboBox with data in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jcombobox

I have a Swings GUI which contains a JComboBox and I want to load data into it from the database.

I have retrieved the data from the database in a String Array. Now how can I populate this String array into the JComboBox

EDITED====================================================================

In actual, the JComboBox is already instantiated when the java GUI is shown to the user. So I can't pass the Array as a paramter to the constructor.

How can I populate the already instantiated JComboBox?

The following is the code that is Nebeans generated code.

```
jComboBox15 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

jComboBox15.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "12" }));

jComboBox15.setName("jComboBox15");
```

Can I set another ComboBoxModel to the above jComboBox?

Comment: now this update makes a little more sense ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an excellent article about it: [How to use Combo Boxes ( The Java Tutorial )](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Basically:

```
String[] dbData = dateFromDb();
JComboBox dbCombo = new JComboBox(dbData);
```

You'll need to know other things like

- Using an Uneditable Combo Box
- Handling Events on a Combo Box
- Using an Editable Combo Box
- Providing a Custom Renderer
- The Combo Box API
- Examples that Use Combo Boxes

That article contains information about it.

**EDIT**

Yeap, you can either do what you show in your edited post, or keep a reference to the combo model:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel dcm = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
combo.setModel( dcm );
....
for( String newRow : dataFetched ) {
    dcm.addElement( newRow )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ah, the combo box is already instantiated.... In that case just clear the contents and add the new array item by item:

```
comboBox.removeAllItems();

for(String str : strArray) {
   comboBox.addItem(str);
}
```

Make sure this is done from the EDT!

Answer (score 3):

```
new JComboBox(stringArray);
```

A useful tip - when you know what class you are working with, check [its javadoc](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html). It most often contains the information you need.

Edit: after your update, use:

```
for (String string : stringArray) {
   comboBox.addItem(string);
}
```

(my tip still applies)

Answer (score 3):

I think that what NetBeans does is what you need.

From wherever you want, you can create a `DefaultComboBoxModel` object and then invoke `comboBox.setModel(defaultComboBox);`

Here is a very small example of what I think you want to do: when the user clicks the button "Change data" the comboBox is filled with data from an array (method `actionPerformed`).

```
public class TestJComboBox extends JFrame {
    private JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();

    public TestJComboBox() {

        JButton changeComboBoxData = new JButton("Change data");
        changeComboBoxData.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                DefaultComboBoxModel cbm = new DefaultComboBoxModel(
                        new String[] { "hola", "adios" });
                comboBox.setModel(cbm);
            }
        });

        super.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        super.setSize(100, 100);
        super.add(changeComboBoxData, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        super.add(comboBox, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestJComboBox().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
JComboBox jComboOperator = new JComboBox();

arrOperatorName = new String []{"Visa", "MasterCard", "American Express"};
jComboOperator.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(arrOperatorName));
```